# SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I get the following error in my PHP script that uses PDO to execute some insert queries on SQL Server.

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.

I don't use any stored procedures, and appending the query with

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

...doesn't help either.

The code seems to have inserted all the records as expected, but the error message bugs me.

Here is a simplified code, as requested...

```
<?php

    $pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=SVR;Database=app', 'app', 'pass', [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ]);

    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM nation');
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://somegame.com/api/nation/id=$result&key=myapikey");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $nation = curl_exec($ch);

            $json = $nation;
            $nation = json_decode($nation, true);

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO nation_record(nation_id,as_on,json) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->execute([ $result, date("Y-m-d"), $json ]);
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        api_log($pdo, $e->getMessage());
    }

    api_log($pdo, 'Completed successfully!');


    function api_log($pdo, $desc) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO api_log(calling_api, description) VALUES (?,?)");

        $stmt->execute([ 'myscript', $desc ]);
    }
```

Comment: Please, post your code. Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov done editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

- The reason for your error is that you are using one variable `$stmt` for your `SELECT` and `INSERT` statements and after the first `INSERT` statement, `while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)) ...` generates the error. Use different variable for the `INSERT` statements.
- The `INSERT` statement has four parameter placeholders in `prepare()`, but only three values in `execute()`.
- Use `PDOStatement::fetchColumn` to return one column in a row.

Code:

```
<?php

    ...
    while ($result = $stmt->fetchColumn(0)) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://somegame.com/api/nation/id=$result&key=myapikey");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $nation = curl_exec($ch);

        $json = $nation;
        $nation = json_decode($nation, true);
 
        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO nation_record(nation_id,as_on,json) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt2->execute([$result, date("Y-m-d"), $json ]);
    }

...
?>
```

Comment: I renamed the subsequent stmt. The parameters were incorrect because I simplified my original code.